# How can I move the color option from the inputs section to the style section?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I move the color option from the inputs section to the style section?

I want to change it the same as the plot style!
Is that possible?

I tried to plot the lower2 for example but didn't work.
Do you have any way to fix it?

I'm new in tradingview pinescript code, I try to learn by myself.
So some problems I don't know how to fix.

````
//@version=5


indicator('chanel', overlay=true)
minLengthInput = 70
lengthInput = 300
col_chanl = input.color(color.red)

// FUNCTIONS
_linreg_slope(source, length) =>
    max_bars_back(source, 600)
    if not barstate.islast or length <= 1
        [float(na), float(na), float(na)]
    else
        sumX = 0.0
        sumY = 0.0
        sumXSqr = 0.0
        sumXY = 0.0
        for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
            val = source[i]
            per = i + 1.0
            sumX += per
            sumY += val
            sumXSqr += per * per
            sumXY += val * per
        slope = (length * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (length * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)
        average = sumY / length
        intercept = average - slope * sumX / length + slope
        [slope, average, intercept]

_linreg_dev(source, length, slope, average, intercept) =>
    max_bars_back(source, 2000)
    upDev = 0.0
    dnDev = 0.0
    stdDevAcc = 0.0
    dsxx = 0.0
    dsyy = 0.0
    dsxy = 0.0
    periods = length - 1
    daY = intercept + slope * periods / 2
    val = intercept
    for j = 0 to periods by 1
        price = high[j] - val
        if price > upDev
            upDev := price
        price := val - low[j]
        if price > dnDev
            dnDev := price
        price := source[j]
        dxt = price - average
        dyt = val - daY
        price -= val
        stdDevAcc += price * price
        dsxx += dxt * dxt
        dsyy += dyt * dyt
        dsxy += dxt * dyt
        val += slope
    stdDev = math.sqrt(stdDevAcc / (periods == 0 ? 1 : periods))
    pearsonR = dsxx == 0 or dsyy == 0 ? 0 : dsxy / math.sqrt(dsxx * dsyy)
    [stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev]

f_data_linreg_channel(length) =>
    [s, a, i] = _linreg_slope(close, length)
    [stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev] = _linreg_dev(close, length, s, a, i)
    startPrice = i + s * (length - 1)
    endPrice = i
    [startPrice, endPrice, stdDev, pearsonR]

f_data_auto_linreg_channel(_min, _len) =>
    var int autoLength = _min
    int volLen = ta.barssince(volume == ta.highest(volume, _len-1))     
    if not na(volLen) and volLen >= minLengthInput and volLen < lengthInput
        autoLength := volLen

    [startPrice1, endPrice1, stdDev1, pearsonR1] = f_data_linreg_channel(autoLength)
    [startPrice2, endPrice2, stdDev2, pearsonR2] = f_data_linreg_channel(minLengthInput)

    startPrice = pearsonR1 > pearsonR2 ? startPrice1 : startPrice2
    endPrice = pearsonR1 > pearsonR2 ? endPrice1 : endPrice2
    stdDev = pearsonR1 > pearsonR2 ? stdDev1 : stdDev2
    pearsonR = pearsonR1 > pearsonR2 ? pearsonR1 : pearsonR2
    [startPrice, endPrice, stdDev, pearsonR, pearsonR1 > pearsonR2 ? autoLength : minLengthInput]

[startPrice, endPrice, stdDev, pearsonR, the_len] = f_data_auto_linreg_channel(minLengthInput, lengthInput)

upperStartPrice1 = startPrice + stdDev
upperEndPrice1 = endPrice + stdDev
upperStartPrice2 = startPrice + 2*stdDev
upperEndPrice2 = endPrice + 2*stdDev
lowerStartPrice1 = startPrice + -stdDev
lowerEndPrice1 = endPrice + -stdDev
lowerStartPrice2 = startPrice + 2*-stdDev
lowerEndPrice2 = endPrice + 2*-stdDev

var line baseLine = line.new(bar_index - the_len + 1, startPrice, bar_index, endPrice, width=2, color=col_chanl)
var line upper1 = line.new(bar_index - the_len + 1, upperStartPrice1, bar_index, upperEndPrice1, width=2, color=col_chanl)
var line lower1 = line.new(bar_index - the_len + 1, lowerStartPrice1, bar_index, lowerEndPrice1, width=2, color=col_chanl)
var line upper2 = line.new(bar_index - the_len + 1, upperStartPrice1, bar_index, upperEndPrice1, width=2, color=col_chanl)
var line lower2 = line.new(bar_index - the_len + 1, lowerStartPrice1, bar_index, lowerEndPrice1, width=2, color=col_chanl)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(baseLine, bar_index - the_len + 1, startPrice)
    line.set_xy2(baseLine, bar_index, endPrice)
    line.set_xy1(upper1, bar_index - the_len + 1, upperStartPrice1)
    line.set_xy2(upper1, bar_index, upperEndPrice1)
    line.set_xy1(lower1, bar_index - the_len + 1, lowerStartPrice1)
    line.set_xy2(lower1, bar_index, lowerEndPrice1)
    line.set_xy1(upper2, bar_index - the_len + 1, upperStartPrice2)
    line.set_xy2(upper2, bar_index, upperEndPrice2)
    line.set_xy1(lower2, bar_index - the_len + 1, lowerStartPrice2)
    line.set_xy2(lower2, bar_index, lowerEndPrice2)```
````

Comment: Posting junk to bypass the quality filter is disingenuous at best. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move that from user input to style tab. The ones in the style tab are generated automatically.

What you can do as a workaround is, add a user input for the style, linewidth and other arguments and use them when you create a line.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay=true)

in_line_style = input.string("Solid", "Style", ["Solid", "Dotted", "Dashed"])
in_line_col = input.color(color.yellow, "Color")
in_line_width = input.int(1, "Width")

line_style = switch in_line_style
    "Solid" => line.style_solid
    "Dotted" => line.style_dotted
    "Dashed" => line.style_dashed

l = line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index+1, close, extend=extend.right, color=in_line_col, style=line_style, width=in_line_width)
line.delete(l[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `col_chanl = input.color(color.red)` part and replace all `col_chanl` funcion inputs to your desired color. ex: `color.red`